# The meaning of ‘autonomous’ in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The right to the truth about gross human rights violations is becoming
> more firmly entrenched in international human rights law. In the past
> decade, the European Court of Human Rights (ECtHR) has also explicitly
> acknowledged the right to the truth.1 As it has gradually been
> developed by a diverse set of actors—in treaties, case law, and
> soft-law documents—the content and contours of the right to the truth
> are subject to ongoing controversies.2 Discussions so far have mostly
> focused on questions such as whether it has the status of an
> **autonomous right**, to what kinds of atrocities it pertains and what
> instruments are necessary to guarantee the right to the truth (in
> particular, whether criminal proceedings are required). ([Source](https://academic.oup.com/hrlr/article/21/4/874/6327498))

What does autonomous mean in the above context? How such kind of rights differ from non-autonomous ones?
Does it mean an independent right? Then what is an independent right? Independent from what? Does it mean a basic right?
How should it be understood?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it comprises several questions and this is a question that requires legal knowledge particularly in the area of Human Rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Paraguay is not aware of a commonly accepted definition of "autonomous
> right". A "conditional right" is a right that depends on an uncertain
> event; a right that may or may not exist". **Thus an "autonomous right"
> could be understood to be a right that does not depend on an uncertain
> event for its existence but solely on the will of the right holder.** An
> autonomous right, like all other rights, may however be exercised only
> consistently with the law. [WTO; *Dispute Settlement Reports 2004*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dispute_Settlement_Reports_2004/5EZCS34oc0EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22autonomous%20right%22%20definition&pg=PA1475&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 3):

It would simplify things to know a bit more about the rather technical term **Right to Truth.**

*Wikipedia* gives:

> Right to truth is the right, in the case of grave violations of human rights, for the victims and their families or societies to have access to the truth of what happened...

As for *autonomous*, it's been used in its most basic sense here, i.e.

*Not controlled by others or by outside forces*; *independent*:

*an autonomous judiciary*; *an autonomous division of a corporate conglomerate.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

I hope it's easy to decode the meaning of the sentence now.

Comment: Still not clear. What feature makes a right autonomous? How autonomous right differ from non-autonomous right?